# What is the best way to prevent a webpage coded completely in HTML (no PHP or any server side language) from caching?

Tags: html, browser, caching

I thought by placing these two lines that it would prevent the page from being cached but this is not the case between the head tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

As already mentioned this is on server that doesn't support PHP (or any server side language, well, that's not true, it has cgi-bin folder that supports perl scripts but I don't know perl and have no time to engage in it.)

What else could I do to prevent the page from caching? It caches on Firefox and IE (and not so much in Chrome or Safari.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure whatever webserver you use to send the right [cache control](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) headers. You can't depend on anything [in the document](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#PRAGMA) itself.