# DO not load a HTML page from cache

Tags: html, caching

Here's what I need to get, the version of the page must be the last. It's a price list, no way i want the price from last week.

So I got some code from everywhere on the web and paste it to my header, here it is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

I dont know if it's enough or what it does, but it must tell the browser:

1. Download the page
2. Forget the cache, it's too old even if you hit reload 10 times in a row. Download it again.

So the question: is it the proper way? It's a HTML only page, no jQuery nor PHP.

Comment: aside the point, cheap isn't the reason to cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `meta` tags have an `http-equiv` attribute because they're a document-level placeholder for items that should be in the HTTP response.  Instead of sending requests for your bare resource, clients should be sending a "GET if not modified since X" request, and they should be set correctly in your header.  Ask your host for reference on how to provide those "no cache" options.

[See this exact duplicate of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676882/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-a-webpage-coded-completely-in-html-no-php-or-an?rq=1) for more information, btw.

Also,  a knowledge-utility basis, add a "Prices good until XXXX" in the content of your page.  It's a price list, so someone will print it out and think that it's still a good price if you don't have an indicator otherwise.

Comment: Sometime you cannot modify server setting... can't go there !